# pointer as a parameter

Tags: pointers, parameters

I have a problem with this function I created, the function should return the number of characters entered in the array. but always return 20 that its the limit of the array itself.

Code:

```
int LongitudCadena (char *pcadena) {
    // cantidad its the counter of chars that in the array
    int cantidad=0;  
    //M its a constant equals 20, that its the limit of the array
    for(int a=0;a<M;a++){  
        if(pcadena!=0){
            pcadena++;   
            cantidad++;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return cantidad;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `if(pcadena!=0)` by `if(*pcadena!='\0')`.

Also, change the `else` condition to either

```
else 
{
   return cantidad;
}
```

or

```
else 
{
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pcadena`, the pointer, is never going to be 0 (NULL)... what you meant that the character it points to is `'\0'`

```
if (*pcadena)
```

Another problem is once you find the terminator, you return `0`. You should return `cantidad` there.

Note: `cantidad == a`

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code. First of all, you should test the content of the address the pointer points at.

```
...
if(*pacadena!=0) {
    ....
```

Secondly, why do you return 0 in the while loop when `pcadena` is 0? Shouldn't you return the current length? Assuming your data always terminate with `\0`, then your `for` loop should look something like this:

```
for(int a=0;a<M;a++){  
    if(*pcadena){
        pcadena++;   
        cantidad++;
    } else {
        return cantidad;
    }
}
```

Further, if your data is indeed terminated by `\0`, then you should just use the `strlen` function instead. There's no need to rewrite this.